# URL in Java code body throws no compile errors

Tags: java, branch, label

In the following code block, `http://dray92.github.io` should throw a compiler error. What is happening here?

```
public void foo() {
    String s = "hi";
    int x = 3 + 2;

    http://dray92.github.io

    double d = 3.14;
    System.out.println(s + " " + x + " " + d);
}
```

Comment: it's a silly trick... don't use it, unless you want to confuse anyone trying to read your code.

Comment: @bayou.io I see what you mean. Just that I have encountered it in a couple places and have found it useful at times. SO didn't really have a question that mentioned this. So, the question-answer style post for potential future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a concept of [labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). In this instance, the label is `http` and the `//dray92.github.io` that follows it is simply treated as a comment.

If you would require jumping to this line `http` from, let's say a `for` loop, you would simply type `break http;`

Answer (score 1):

In java labels are only provided for iteration statements and switch statements. It is not like C's labels.

```
one: for(....){
    two: for(....){
        break one;           // it will break iteration of first for loop
    }
}
```

Comment: no, in java, you can label and break any statement.